# Problema al asociar DNS de Heroku a Nic.ar

Tags: url, heroku, dns

quiero asociar mi dirección comprada en Nic.ar a un proyecto alojado en Heroku, y no me funcionan los DNS que me provee Heroku, alguna guia de como realizar esto ? , gracias .

Answer (score 4):

Luego de leer foros desactualizados, logre que funcionara la siguiente manera:

1- En la seccion Settings, agregar el dominio que compramos en nic argentina, por cada dominio agregado Heroku nos otorga un dns target.
(Recuerden que heroku utiliza ip dinamicas para nuestros sitios)

[image: Settings - Domains]

2 - Instale el add-on en Heroku llamado PointDns, lo cual nos da la direccion de DNS que tenemos que ingresar en Nic argentina.
Las direcciones se encuentran en la columna data, de tipo NS.
Ej: (dns12.pointhq.com ,dns15.pointhq.com)

[image: PointDNS]

3- Luego en la opcion de Nic argentina, donde se administra los dominios,  agregue una nueva delegación, colocando los DNS de PointDns:

[image: Delegacion de dominio en NIC.ar]

En las imágenes url.com.ar seria mi dominio comprado en NIC.ar, espero se haya entendido.

Comment: Franco, "...por cada dominio agregado Heroku nos otorga un dns target...", hay que usar en algun lado esos dns target? Gracias!

Comment: Hola Ismael, no, yo no los use en ningún lado, solo use los que me otorgo PointDns registrándolos en nic.ar, saludos!

Comment: PointDns no lo puedo agregar y eso que mi cuenta está verificada, error:
Item could not be created:
An error was encountered when contacting the add-on partner to create pointdns:developer. Please try again later. Alguna idea? mil gracias

Comment: Pude hacer funcionar el dominio, pero sigo teniendo errores con SSL, alguno pudo solucionarlo? Tengo el ALIAS y CNAME apuntando al dns de Heroku y no a la app, pero el sitio no carga si intento entrar por https

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Verifica que los Nameservers que te provee Heroku esteen ingresados correctamente en tu panel de NIC.Ar.
> 2. Verifica que en tu panel de Heroku estee asignado el dominio a tu proyecto correctamente.
> 3. Verifica ingresando al dominio que aparezca la web de alguna de las dos empresas o en todo caso un error diciendo que no se ha encontrado la dirección IP del dominio (Es por qué debes esperar la propagación de los DNS)
>
> 3.1 Puedes verificar la dirección IP donde apunta desde la siguiente página con DNS Lookup http://ping.eu

Answer (score 1):

Los pasos de Franco me sirvieron casi en su totalidad, pero los certificados daban error al acceder por HTTPS.

La modificación es que en el PointDNS hay que **apuntar los registros CNAME y ALIAS a los DNS que provee Heroku** (*<dns_server>.herokudns.com*), no a la app (*<your_app>.herokuapp.com*) en sí.

Con esa modificación, todo anduvo perfecto.

Comment: No entendi bien lo que hiciste, me podrias explicar mejor la parte que pusiste entre ()?

Comment: Adentro del primer par de paréntesis iría la URL del DNS que te da Heroku, por ej. *morning-alpaca-kipwrgyh45ceod8mib216juq.herokudns.com*.

En el segundo par de paréntesis iría la URL de la aplicación en sí, o sea *morning-alpaca.herokuapp.com*.

La idea es que hay que apuntar los registros CNAME y ALIAS al primero (DNS de Heroku), no al segundo (URL de la app en sí).

Answer (score 0):

Lo que indicó Franco me sirvió. Pero para que me funcione tuve que usar en "data" de PointDns el "DNS Target" que te indica Heroku para que funcione correctamente.

Comment: No entendi bien, me podrias explicar?

Answer (score 0):

complementando la respuesta, esto tambien sirve para NIC Chile.

Agrega un dominio en app de heroku

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego dentro de tu app heroku:
resources--> addons --> buscar "pointDNS" y agregar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora te cambias a la pagina de pointDNS y agregas la app:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**y ahora IMPORTANTE: cambias el ALIAS por el DNS que te aparece en HEROKU**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo ultimo es que en NIC debes colocar los DNS que aparecen el listado de pointDNS (todos los que tengan NS)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]